STM32MP157D-DK1 OS building
I am trying to flash binaries that I have generated with Yocto, intended for an STM32MP157D-DK1 board. However, during the process, I am encountering the following error: 'Partition 0xBB not found in TSV file' Why is it necessary for this specific partition (0xBB) to exist?
